# ServiceModel vs ServiceInterface in Servicestack

Tags: servicestack

What is the correct approach to structure a ServiceStack project?

As of now I do it in the following way:
Under `ServiceModel`,
I have all the models (entities), and have defined the different routes ("/product") and so on.

Then should all the CRUD operations should be under `ServiceInterface`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the different projects are covered in the [Create your first WebService docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice#step-4-exploring-the-servicestack-solution) (from [Physical Project Structure](http://docs.servicestack.net/physical-project-structure) docs).

Essentially all DTOs accepted and returned by your Services should be in your dep-free `*.ServiceModel` project. All your Service implementation and supporting classes should be in your `*.ServiceInterface` project. If your project gets too big you can move your supporting classes into different projects. You can also split your [Service implementations across multiple assemblies](http://docs.servicestack.net/modularizing-services) although I'd only do that after moving supporting functionality into different projects first.

As you're new to ServiceStack I'd also recommend skimming through other docs for background reading on developing Services and structuring your solution:

- [Design RESTful Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/design-rest-services)
- [Design Message-based APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/design-message-based-apis)
- [Complexity, Services and Role of DTOs](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-complexity-and-dto-roles)